# HDMI disconnected after long suspend

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, suspend, hdmi

After overnight suspend and unplugging monitors from my MSI GS65, I cannot get the HDMI monitor to work (the screen stays black, with a message "No signal detected" when plugged in the computer, or when I turn if off and on again)
I have a second monitor plugged on USB-C (on HDMI through an adapter) and this one works perfectly fine.

`xrandr` show the port as disconnected:
`HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`

The monitor is still *somewhat* recognized by the system, since I can put my mouse and even windows on it (I have to go through it to get to the second monitor).

Rebooting the computer does not solve the problem.

Yesterday I managed to get it to work by reinstalling and rebooting my nvidia drivers twice, but that's not a viable solution.

Other solutions found online did not work.

[edit] The non-working monitor works when I plug it on USB-C through HDMI adapter, so the hardware is ok.

The non-working screen is not marked as "PRIME Display" in `nvidia-settings` > "X Server Display Configuration", but I'm not sure what it means.
[image: No PRIME Display]

[edit2]
I can actually get it to work with `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1280x720`, but it turns back to black with `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080`

Setup:
Ubuntu 16.04 (I never got it to work on 18.04), with Windows on dual boot
MSI GS65, with Nvidia and intel graphic drivers. 1 USB-C output, 1 HDMI output.

Comment: I have three displays. Occasionally the one with Thunderbolt USB-C adapter will get "no signal". I simply unplug and plug the USB-C adapter in again. Then it works fine until next time. It will also happen with Windows 10 so I know it's not a Ubuntu or Linux driver issue.

Comment: I have windows on dual boot and both monitors work fine there. The USB-C works fine in both windows and linux, only the HDMI output in Ubuntu doesn't work. Unplugging and replugging doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on ubuntu 20.04.
In spite of plugged in HDMI cable, it has prompted `No Signal` in the monitor and the `xrandr` returned this:

```
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

In the **Additional Drivers**, `using X.Org X server` as display driver solved my problem!

Comment: As I don't have this configuration anymore, I am unable to test your solution. If it gets a few upvotes and/or comments showing this actually solves the problem, I'll be happy to validate your answer!

Comment: @ThierryJ. Run the following command: `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`. if you have removed the `nouveau`, you can re-install it by `sudo apt install nouveau-firmware`.